# Can I force a screen session on a user?

Tags: centos, gnu-screen

How can I watch another user's shell session? I'd like to evaluate another user's behavior. I'm looking into using screen, but I don't know how to force his terminal to start a screen session.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

You can set screen as the login shell for the user with

```
  usermod -s /usr/bin/screen guest
```

Logging can be set in `/etc/screenrc`

Comment: Will that only take effect when he logs in? Because he's already logged in, and I don't want to log him out thus disrupt his work, I just want to make sure he's not being naughty.

Comment: If a user has logged in, monitoring possibilities would vary even if everything she is doing is legitimate. You might look at shell history after she logs off, but if she runs a different shell or midnight commander, you would have to trace relevant history files as well.

Comment: A key logger of some sort might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try tailing the users bash history if you don't want to make them log off.

Log in, and run `tail -f /home/<username>/.bash_history`.